# which is the best method used for checking isarray

Tags: javascript

I want to check a variable is it array?

which is the best method used for this to get better performance.

`isArray`

or

`instanceof`

Comment: Array.isArray would be the native way and probably the best if the browser supports it.

Comment: In practically all cases any performance difference is minuscule, and in any case where the difference is meaningful you could just measure it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Big guys (Jquery, underscore) do it like this:

```
  isArray = Array.isArray || function(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]';
  };
```

But <s>these are not the droids you're looking for</s> you actually don't need this at all. Don't "check" your variables - just know them.

Comment: When you refer to the "big guys" you should also say that they are hoisting the toString method `var toString = Object.prototype.toString;`...  An inside the function: `return toString.call(..`

Answer (score 2):

Array.IsArray would be better to use.

Also check this [`instanceof` considered harmful (or how to write a robust `isArray`)](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/)

> The problems arise when it comes to scripting in multi-frame DOM
>   environments. In a nutshell, Array objects created within one iframe
>   do not share [[Prototype]]’s with arrays created within another
>   iframe. Their constructors are different objects and so both
>   instanceof and constructor checks fail:

Also you can check the speed variation between the two and you will find that isArray is comparatively faster.

Here is a link to check that:- **[Array.isArray vs instanceof Array](http://jsperf.com/array-isarray-vs-instanceof-array)**

Below code is used to check the speed variation:

```
<script>
  Benchmark.prototype.setup = function() {
    var a = [1, 2, 3];
    var s = 'example';
    var f = false;
  };
</script>
```

Using Array.IsArray:

```
(Array.isArray(a) && (Array.isArray(s) || Array.isArray(f)));
```

it performed nearly **25,255,693 ops/sec**

Now using instanceof:-

```
 (a instanceof Array && (s instanceof Array || f instanceof Array));
```

it performed nearly **21,594,618 ops/sec**

ie, **instanceOf is 15% slower than using IsArray.**

Comment: In other words if you use `isArray` you save 6.7 nanoseconds.

Comment: @Juhana:- Exactly. Nice calculation! +1